# aws permission denied (publickey) with git-codecommit

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to connect to `SSH` to connect to amazon `code-commit` so my steps:

1. create new ssh called: `asw-code-commit` with `asw-code-commit.pub`
2. upload the ssh to asw user IAM and got my `SSH key ID`
3. update config in `.ssh` folder to this:

   ```
   Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
   User APKAV66BIP########
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aws-code-commit
   ```
4. save and connect to ssh by this:

   ```
   ssh git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
   ```

I got this error:

```
no such identity: /Users/Ra/.ssh/aws-code-commit: No such file or directory
APKAV66BI#####@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Does the `/Users/Ra/.ssh/aws-code-commi` actually exist?

Comment: @Marcin of course! see the .shh folder: https://ibb.co/SJhpd7q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the screenshot the file is called (**spelling mistake**):

```
asw-code-commit
```

but it should be:

```
aws-code-commit
```

Comment: Sir if you don't mind can you pls see why this error happened  while deploying  repo from codeCommit by pipelines to Elastic Beanstalk! img1: https://ibb.co/RY2Yzkj  img2:https://ibb.co/Pg060qY

Comment: @jea You have to check EB logs and identify which command failed. Possibily something from your `.ebextentions`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/GQBJM3V  this is the EB logs! sorry for bothering  you but I"m new with AWS

Comment: @jea You can download a zip with full logs (Logs menu in EB console) and look for more details. I think a good idea would be to make a new question specific to this failed deployment. You can then provide relevant details (what are you deploying), any error messages. This way other can also see it and assist.

Comment: Ok sir I will create new question with full details!

Comment: Sir just asking it's ok to include the whole file of log with the question? there is no something dangerous worry about it in file?